# Validate that dropdown values are all distinct from one another with Javascript and/or Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation

I have a form with 7 dropdowns, all containing the values 1-7.

What is the easiest way to validate (using a function) that all of the "selected" values are distinct from one another using Javascript and/or Jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Query all elements, push values to array, check if array has no duplicates.

Comment: I like this solution! Let see if I can make something like this work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create array that contains 1-7 values
2. In first dropdown add all these 7 values
3. On the "OnSelect" event of the first dropdown remove the selected value from array and add the array in 2nd dropdown.

This will add all the values in 2nd dropdown except the one selected in first dropdown

1. Continue for all the 7 dropdowns

Comment: I see where your thought is headed with this one, but it sounds like this solution assumes that the user would be selecting items from the dropdowns in a specific order.

Comment: My situation is a form with 7 dropdowns, where any of them could be interacted with at any time. The user would not need to follow an order.

Comment: Everytime when user select value from dropbox remove that value from array and update all drop boxes with remaining values. ;)